# How do I fix a permission error using Cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

I am trying to do authentications with Cancan in my Rails app and am having trouble doing so.  I have 2 columns in my user table named admin and owner, both of which are boolean.  My ability.rb file checks if this is true and then offers the appropriate permissions.  It seems that the permissions for a user that isn't signed in + a user that is an admin work.  However, the permission for an owner doesn't seem to work.  I'm not able to view the link in my view that utilizes this permission.

I have put load_authorize_resource at the top of my PlacesController.

```
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new  # Guest user
    if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
    else
        can :read, :all
        if user.owner?
            can :create, Place
        end
    end

    # can :read, :all
end
```

I'm able to view this as an admin, but not as an owner...but I should be able to as an owner.

```
<% if can? :create, @place %>
    <%= link_to 'New place', new_place_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write,

```
 <% if can? :create, Place %>
  <%= link_to 'New place', new_place_path %>
 <% end %>
```

Create works on class level rather than object.